# Flickr API Invalid oauth token

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth, flickr

I am working on cordova application that must interact with **Flickr API**. So I use JS to work with its API.

I need to authenticate in app for uploading photos to flickr and comment photos of other users.

[Here is user authentication guide](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html)

In result of my queries i'm getting an access token:

```
{
  "fullname": USER_FULLNAME,
  "oauth_token": "72157660402905810-b99d9b1b0d0101f7",
  "oauth_token_secret": "d8fff950a8ed891e",
  "user_nsid": USER_NSID,
  "username": USER_NAME
 }
```

It seems good, but method flickr.auth.checkToken says me that my token is broken:

`{"stat":"fail","code":98,"message":"Invalid auth token"}`

And of course I can not use any methods that require authorizing with this token.

There is method to exchange this token to token from new API of flickr: [it's documentation](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.auth.oauth.getAccessToken.html). But it returns the same answer.

```
var data = {
        method: `flickr.auth.oauth.getAccessToken`,
        api_key: api_key,
        oauth_token: oauth_data.oauth_token
      };
      //flickerAPI.get_api_sig - getting list of
      //arguments and creating a string that look's like
      //SECRETa1b4c3 and after return md5 hash string.
      data.api_sig = flickrAPI.get_api_sig(data, oauth_data.oauth_token_secret);
      var url = `https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/`;
      url += `?method=${data.method}`;
      url += `&api_key=${data.api_key}`
      url += `&auth_token=${data.oauth_token}`;
      url += `&api_sig=${data.api_sig}`;
```

In result i'm getting such query
`https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.auth.oauth.getAccessToken&api_key=MY_API_KEY&auth_token=72157660402905810-b99d9b1b0d0101f7&api_sig=4365c14cd05c75616e24825570e63d9c`

`{"stat":"fail","code":98,"message":"Invalid auth token"}`

What can be a reason of such behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately i could not solve this problem so i decided to reject idea to use flickr authorization.

Comment: late to this post, but ther would be no reason to even have an old token, the original call you're making is already for the new oauth token/secret. The reason the `checkToken` call fails is fairly obvious, and explained on https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.auth.checkToken.html - it's for checking tokens from the obsolete, not-oauth method of access tokens Flickr used to use. Why were you even using it? Once you have that oauth access token and secret, you're done, use those to sign all the "needs auth" Flickr API calls.